# Choropleth in folium: can not find key_on

Tags: python, geolocation, geospatial, geojson, folium

I have boundaries in geo-json format

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'STATEFP10': '04',
    'ZCTA5CE10': '85347'},
   'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [[[-113.587371, 32.77836],
      [-113.587269, 32.77819],
      [-113.590707, 32.776887],
     ...
```

I have also some data

```
data

POSTCODE    X
0   85347   0
1   85356   0
```

I am trying to plot a basic Choropleth.
If I do the following, I get

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What is wrong in the following snippet? It is an example copied and pasted...
I have already ensured boundaries keys and dataframe postcodes to be exactly same set...

```
m = folium.Map( zoom_start=8)
# Add the color for the chloropleth:
folium.Choropleth(
 geo_data=boundaries,
 name='choropleth',
 data=data,
 columns=['POSTCODE','X'],
 key_on='features.properties.ZCTA5CE10',
 fill_color='BuPu',
#fill_opacity=0.7
).add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

Comment: try feature instead of features for the key_on param ie `feature.properties.ZCTA5CE10`

Comment: That worked! Regardless of the actual field name in the geoson. Can you make it an answer?

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a weird one.  I'll post an answer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try feature instead of features for the key_on param ie `feature.properties.ZCTA5CE10`

From the Choropleth [docstring](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.features.Choropleth)

> key_on: string, default None
>       Variable in the `geo_data` GeoJSON file to bind the data to. Must
>       start with 'feature' and be in JavaScript objection notation.
>       Ex: 'feature.id' or 'feature.properties.statename'.